# Running docker exec in Java

Tags: java, bash, docker, exec

I run a command from terminal and it work, the command is:

> docker exec mysql-container /bin/sh -c "./build/update-time.sh 1559652300000"

I want to be able to do this in JAVA, so i have tried the following but failed. Any ideas how to make it work?

```
public class DockerUtils {
    public static DockerComposeRule docker;
    public static DockerComposeExecOption option = DockerComposeExecOption.noOptions();

    public static void updateTime() {
                                                                //also tried "bin/sh", "-c"
        DockerComposeExecArgument args = DockerComposeExecArgument.arguments("bash", "-c", "./build/update-time.sh 1559652300000");

        //this fails
        docker.exec(option, "mysql-container", args);
    }
}
```

Throws `java.lang.NullPointerException`

```
$> docker ps
(I had to cut the output below, but there is a container with the name!)
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE   COMMAND    CREATED    STATUS   PORTS   NAMES
ce1e1d33dcef   xx       xx          xx        xx      xx      mysql-container
```

Comment: Looks like you don't have a container with the name `mysql-container` running. Can you see this with `docker ps`

Comment: To execute `docker exec` try to check if you've previously executed `docker run`: Maybe mysql-container doesn't exist.

Comment: @SaqibAhmed - Container exist

Comment: @AlexGalera - no, container exist and is running